# Create internal testing release error when upload App bundles to google play

Tags: codenameone

I send Android build with build hint android.appBundle=true.
And upload the aab file to google play for creating internal testing release with the option "Let Google manage and protect your app signing key (recommended)".

But I get the error "The Android App Bundle was not signed."

I also try "Export and upload a key from Java keystore" option but still failed with the same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create an Android Certificate before creating the build?

If you don't create a certificate we print a warning but let you send a debug build. This probably won't work for Google Play though.

Comment: Yes, I do create an Android Certificate by Certificate Generator in Control Center. I send Android Build that is not a debug build.

Comment: Verify two things. Download the bundle/APK and check that they are signed using Android APK inspector tools. Also look in codenameone_settings.properties and make sure the certificate settings there are correct and weren't corrupted by a git merge or something.

Comment: You are right. I create an Android Certificate but choose the debug build option.
After I choose the release build option, I can create the internal testing release.
Thanks so much.