# Internal testing's run time error only encountered on app downloaded from Google play

Tags: codenameone

I have an app being sent to android build successfully.
I install the app by OTA click to install on codename one build and run it successfully.
I upload the aab file to Play console for internal testing.
Run the app downloaded from Google Play with internal testing, error encountered.
The screenshot below

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71949015/create-internal-testing-release-error-when-upload-app-bundles-to-google-play) you used a debug build up until now. I'm guessing the release build is failing for you because it's obfuscated and doesn't contain debug information. Without further details I'll bet you have code such as `getClass().getName()` or something of this type in your application that's causing this problem.

You need to connect the device with a cable and view the device logs with logcat or something similar. There you'll be able to get a stack trace to your specific error. You can de-obfuscate the stack trace using the mapping file from your build. Notice that this is VERY build specific. You can't use a mapping file from a different build...

Note that even an obfuscated Android stack trace is still relatively readable but if you want more... You would need the stack trace and the mapping file matching this EXACT version. Then follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56007176/756809).